# Where should I use XSP.endAjaxLoading()?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a Xpage that takes too long to load. So the client ask me to do a loading indicator.
I searched and found `XSP.startAjaxLoading()`, that I put in onClientLoad event of the Custom Control.
But now I don't know where should I put `XSP.endAjaxLoading()` to make the loading screen go away.
I'tried to use in afterRenderResponse and beforeRenderResponse: `view.postScript("XSP.endAjaxLoading()")`, since this comand is CSJS, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will it work if you wrap XSP. endAjaxLoading() in a XSP.addOnLoad() method?

Comment: Please share your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this answer as solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35481981/5339322
I've saw it a few days ago, what made me think twice is that using this i should know what is doing my XPages to delay. I ran some tests and discovered what, and it was a call to a method in the afterRestoreView event, then I migrated it to onClientLoad event and used the solution in the answer above cited.
But I'm afraid that I have to keep an eye on it, so if someone adds some code that delays in one of the another events of XPages I have to move it again, of course, if it's possible, if it's not, I'll figure it out something diferent.

Thanks for all the answers ans comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put it in the onComplete event.  That can be difficult to find.  You typically need to use the outline control to find it.

I have a video demo on NotesIn9 that has an example on this.

http://www.notesin9.com/2016/02/19/notesin9-188-adding-a-please-wait-to-xpages/?unique=http%3A//www.notesin9.com/2016/02/19/notesin9-188-adding-a-please-wait-to-xpages/

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt (`view.postscript`) works only with full/partial updates and does not work for page loading.

You have used `onClientLoad` - which is executed when your page is finished with loading. I guess you get ajax animation after a while and it won't stop.

You should make preload screen - very simple XPage which starts animation and does not care to turn it off. In `onClientLoad` event redirect to your slow XPage. That will discard the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using the Standby Dialog XSnippet https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control. I use it as a standard in all XPages applications.

Comment: That's only for Partial refreshes right?  That doesn't touch the initial page load if that takes a while.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I don't think there can be a resolution for initial page load. All components need to be processed on the server. If that's where the performance impact is, you need to consider using Dynamic Content Control or Loaded property, where appropriate. Otherwise, you need to cut down the amount of content on the page or pre-calculate some data. Once processed on the server, it sends all HTML, including onClientLoad code to the browser. The resolution then is not specific to XPages, but general web development.

Comment: I think the resolution is what I did in the NotesIn9 video.  Fake it so the page loads and then after initial load do a partial refresh for the long running process.