# Loading Indicator in XPages initial Load

Tags: xpages, loading, lotus-notes, lotus

My Xpage is taking to much time to load. So I was requested to make a loading indicator that should dissapear only when the page is completely functional.
I tried to use `XSP.startAjaxLoading()`, but I couldn't figure it out where i put `XSP.endAjaxLoading()`.

Comment: Do you and Eleonardo Oliveira know each other? :-) See Eleonardo's almost exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427156/where-should-i-use-xsp-endajaxloading

Comment: Ok, please only add one question then. Looking forward to hear about your solution (as an answer)

Comment: Even he already found the answer. Thank you!

Comment: If he found the answer he should either accept one of the given answer or if different answer his own question with the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading Indicator Page Full Refresh in XPages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476847/loading-indicator-page-full-refresh-in-xpages)

Answer (score 1):

Create a lightweight fast loading XPage which

- shows loading indicator on client side and
- calls your real initial XPage with `window.location = "your.xsp"` on onClientLoad event.

This will show the loading indicator as long the main XPage is not rendered yet.

Comment: Thanks we found the answer in:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35481981/5339322

Answer (score 0):

Try pace.js (http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)
Domino tutorial is available here: http://planetlotus.org/profiles/frankvanderlinden_142706

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways of doing this, but the easiest would be to create a div that constantly show the loading on the client and this can be achieved by writing a simple css.

The css below is copied from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp):
**CSS:**

```css
.loader {
       border: 5px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
       border-top: 5px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
       border-radius: 50%;
       width: 40px;
       height: 40px;
       animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
   }

   @keyframes spin {
       0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
       100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
   }
```

**Script to display load:**

```js
function showLoad() {
 document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = 'block';
}
```

**Div in xpage:**

```html
<div class="loader" id="spinner" style="display:none"></div>
<xp:button value="Display Load" id="button1">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
  <xp:this.script><![CDATA[showLoad();]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

I hope this helps.